# Отменить revert в svn

Tags: visual-studio, svn

Доброго времени суток!

Есть проект в visual studio, контролируется svn.
Я создал несколько классов, хотел закоммитить в репозиторий.
Но вместо коммита, случайно нажал revert!
И классы удалились. Как их вернуть?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Оказывается, что если ревернуть файлы, которые ты создал и их еще нет в svn, то они не удаляются, а просто исключаются из проекта.

Comment: Потому что надо командной строкой пользоваться )) Нельзя так опечататься в слове `commit`, чтобы получилось `revert`. А еще лучше пользоваться Git. Там есть шансы восстановиться после подобной операции: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424315/181472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Максимум -- попытаться воспользоваться утилитами, которые восстанавливают удаленные файлы с диска.