# Можно ли вернуть несохраненные файлы после git checkout . или git reset --hard?

Tags: git, git-checkout

По ошибке удалил изменения, которые *не успел сохранить в коммит*. 
Можно как-то восстановить изменения файлов?

Стер одним из следующих способов:

- `git checkout .`
- `git reset --hard`
- Просто удалил файлы с диска

*(на самом деле, если коммита не было, способ удаления никак не влияет на возможность восстановления)*

Comment: `man git-reset` или `git help reset` - оно? Ну и поковыряться в локальной истории, любые приличные IDE это умеют: http://ato.su/resizer/i/a/f/97fcf661.jpg

Comment: Если вы в результате этого потеряли незакомиченные файлы - никак (хотя на всякий случай проверьте staging area через git status). Если вам нужно вернуться к закоммиченной версии - `git checkout нужный-коммит`

Comment: Добавил решение с восстановлением файлов.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Как предотвратить

Чтобы такое с вами больше не случилось, отменяйте изменения безопасным способом:

```
git stash save
```

Эта команда отменяет все изменения в рабочей области и в индексе (относительно `HEAD`), сохраняя их в stash. Потом его можно использовать либо удалить.

```
# использовать
git stash apply

# удалить
git stash drop
```

#### Как восстановить

Для начала, проверьте историю и временные файлы своего текстового редактора или среды разработки. Многие из них делают собственные бэкапы по ходу работы на случай непредвиденных обстоятельств.

Если измененная версия файлов сначала была добавлена (проиндексирована, `git add`), то так:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

Каждый найденный объект будет выложен в папку `.git/lost-found/other/` в том же виде, в каком и был (т.е. не blob), но с `sha1` соответствующего blob'a вместо имени. Таким образом, содержимое файлов восстановить можно, имена - нельзя.

Если файлы не были даже проиндексированы и `git checkout .` - то средствами Git никак не восстановить.

Answer (score 0):

`git reflog`
пишет логи коммитов и прочего. В ней надо найти id коммита к которому ты хочешь вернуться и потом сделать резет:
`git reset --hard adha211ed` *<--Это id коммита*

В моём случае я случайно удалил все командой `git checkout -d somebranch`.

Comment: Нет. В вопросе явно спросили "которые не успел сохранить в коммит". Поэтому искать в рефлоге нечего.

Answer (score 0):

столкнулся с такой же проблемой. в PyCharm я смог это исправить. в файле в котором были изменения - нажимаешь Ctrl+Z  и в появившемся окне подтверждаешь