# Восстанление состояния ветки

Tags: git, git-reset

Можно ли восстановить состояние файлов после выполнения `git reset --hard`, если не был сделан `commit`?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424384/178576

Comment: если не делал add хотя-бы то через git никак, т.к. при просто reset меняется только .git/index но есть призрачная возможность восстановить через fs

Comment: Да, можно. Читайте мой ответ, ссылку на который выше дал Alexander Barakin. Если появятся дополнительные вопросы — задавайте их в комментариях к тому ответу (не вопросу!). Я их там увижу. Либо приходите в этот чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26116/git--ru-so

Comment: @NickVolynkin, помог Ваш ответ в дублирующем [вопросе] (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424315/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-git-checkout)

Comment: @zb': кстати, намекните на путь решения через `fs`?