# Как восстановить проект имея только папку .git?

Tags: git

Как восстановить проект имея только папку `.git`?

Размер папки нормальный (не ноль) и `git log` выводит все коммиты.

Comment: уточните вопрос, какой язык и IDE используются, возможна альтернатива например, если вы писали в Android Studio\Intellij idea, то там есть локальная история.

Comment: Мой вопрос связан больше с работой с git, без привязки к IDE. Но тут попутно возник вопрос - а что Android Studio где-то еще хранит проекты, кроме их папок?

Comment: android studio как и любая основанная на intellij ide хранит некоторое количество локальных изменений. большой проект из них не восстановить

Comment: Если какие-то файлы были индексированы, но не вошли в коммит, их всё равно можно восстановить: [Можно ли вернуть несохраненные файлы после `git checkout .`?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424315/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-git-checkout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вы можете резетнуться на коммит (`git reset --hard`) или сделать `git checkout .`  в корне репозитория - если не закоммитили удаление всех файлов. если закоммитили - вам надо резетнуться на последний коммит (`git log`)

в приведенном примере мы создаем репу, добавляем файл, удаляем, остается только папка `.git`, восстанавливаемся из нее обоими способами. (до нового коммита и с помощью резета)

```
-user~/temp$ mkdir gtest
-user~/temp$ cd gtest
-user~/temp/gtest$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/temp/gtest/.git/
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ touch 123
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ echo 123 > 123
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ kommit done
## Initial commit on master
?? 123
[master (root-commit) d6089c5] done
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 123
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ rm 123
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    123

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ git checkout .
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ ls
123
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ git log
commit d6089c549be7b2e922f1d1b31960ee34166d1ae6
Author: user <“user@user.com”>
Date:   Sat Jul 30  2016 +0300

    done
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ git reset --hard d6089c549be7b2e922f1d1b31960ee34166d1ae6
HEAD is now at d6089c5 done
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$ ls
123
-user~/temp/gtest (master)$
```

P.S.
команда `kommit` это алиас типа

```
function gitAddAndCommit(){
    git status -bs
    git add . ; git commit -m "$1" --no-verify
}
alias kommit=gitAddAndCommit
```

P.P.S.
`(master)`  в prompt - это имя текущей ветки, что-то в [этом духе](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt). 
Очень удобная штука.