# В NetBeans сделан был откат

Tags: git, netbeans

Как вернуть к тому, что было до отката?
Оно было без фиксации.

Comment: Всё очень плохо... Если не было фиксаций, и если в отдельных документах нет опций "Отмены" предыдущих действий - вернуть изменения вряд ли удастся. Сочувствую.

Comment: История изменений (самого Netbeans) вам в помощь

Comment: Если файлы были хотя бы индексированы (`git add`),  то сработает это решение: [Можно ли вернуть несохраненные файлы после `git checkout .`?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424315/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-git-checkout)