# Можно ли отменить последний чекаут в SmartGit?

Tags: git, smartgit

Давно не коммитил в SmartGit, и сделал chеckout на последний коммит. В итоге моя актуальная последняя несохранённая версия заменилась старой, месячной давности. Можно ли сделать какое-то ctrl+z и вернуть мою последнюю версию? И возможно ли это сделать вообще?

Comment: судя по описанию, вы сделели не просто `git checkout ...`, а `git checkout -f ...` (т.е., с опцией `-f|--force`). если вы не добавляли своих изменений в индекс и не делали резервных копий, то эти изменения, судя по приведённой вами информации, утеряны.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin  smartgit оказался совсем не smart.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете поискать бэкапы в следующих местах:

- Временные файлы вашего редактора или среды разработки.
- Если перед чекаутом вы добавляли файлы, то git наверняка ещё хранит их, так что [восстановить можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424315/181472).

> Давно не коммитил в SmartGit... заменилась старой, месячной давности.

Делайте коммиты часто. Каждый раз, когда у вас есть какой-то осмысленный результат работы. Обычно это 5-10 раз в день. Потом лишние коммиты можно будет объединить в один.

Также рекомендую вам удалить SmartGit и научиться пользоваться командной строкой. С ней вы бы не потеряли свои изменения, выполняя команду `git checkout`. (С `git checkout -f` смогли бы потерять, но это уже было бы осознанное действие.)