# Посмотреть, кто сделал git reset

Tags: git, git-reset, git-log

Так сложилось, что пришлось добавить в коллаборацию несколько человек, свосем не имеющих опыта работы с git. Видимо, кто-то из них сделал git reset и удалил коммиты за прошедшие два дня. Вот, вопрос, как востановить данные и как найти того, кто резетнул. Была мысль поискать в git log, но там ничего похожего не видно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424315/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо. Но там только про востановление, хотелось бы найти, кто сделал reset и объяснить, что больше так делать не стоит. Ну и вообще для общего развития, как-то можно посмотреть полную историю изменений, включая git reset?

Comment: Reset меняет локальный репозиторий. Вот push может изменить удаленный.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Ну, это понятно. Я говорю про изменения, внесенные в удаленный репозиторий. Если бы кто-то сделал reset только в своем локальном репе, я бы даже не узнал.

Comment: А какой у вас удаленный репозиторий? На каком-то хостинге вроде github/gitlab/bitbucket/gogs или просто в расшаренной по сети папке?

Comment: @NickVolynkin github

Comment: Вообще-то в нормальных командах это обсуждают без претензий. А вам урок, что нужно проводить тренинги.

Comment: @0andriy Да, понимаю. Проблема в том, что нормально опросить людей не получится - нет адекватных средств коммуникации. В общем, все не просто. Да мы и не комманда. Практику для вуза делает три группы, но отчет должен быть общим. Вот отсюда все проблемы.